# Sliding Boxes Growing in Height

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get each individual box to slide up with content on hover but am unable to figure out how to the hover part to increase in height. So if the box was 350px x 350px and you hovered over it, it would increase in height to 650px x 350px to allow for a heading, text and a button. I have tried to increase the height based on :hover but tha obv didn't work.

Should I be using flex for this?
Can I accomplish this with CSS?
Can I use transition height on hover?

Does anyone have any suggestions as I am stumped.

Here is my code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 17rem);
  gap: 2rem;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  height: 19rem;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0.1rem 0.1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.item h3 {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: turquoise;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.item a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.item a:hover ~ .item__overlay, .item a:focus ~ .item__overlay {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item__overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform 300ms;
  background-color: #82ebe0;
  transform: translate3d(0, calc(100% - 3.5rem), 0);
}

.item__body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.item__body p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#0" aria-labelledby="person1"></a>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590424744257-fdb03ed78ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
        <div class="item__overlay">
            <h3 id="person1" aria-hidden="true">Person 1</h3>
            <div class="item__body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#0" aria-labelledby="person2"></a>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590424744257-fdb03ed78ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
        <div class="item__overlay">
            <h3 id="person2" aria-hidden="true">Person 2</h3>
            <div class="item__body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#0" aria-labelledby="person3"></a>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590424744257-fdb03ed78ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
        <div class="item__overlay">
            <h3 id="person3" aria-hidden="true">Person 3</h3>
            <div class="item__body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#0" aria-labelledby="person4"></a>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590424744257-fdb03ed78ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
        <div class="item__overlay">
            <h3 id="person4" aria-hidden="true">Person 4</h3>
            <div class="item__body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code? the hover seems to work fine

Comment: I need it to scale in height on hover.

Comment: I need it to scale in height in order to add more text on hover.

Comment: this is what your code is actually doing

Comment: No, if I add more text to the first box, it cuts it off.

Comment: @idiosyncratic you'll need to use javascript because you are working with heights based on amount of content and not fixed/relative to other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make the height based on the content and the image `position:absolute`

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 17rem);
  grid-auto-rows:1fr; /* remove this if you don't want equal rows*/
  gap: 2rem;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0.1rem 0.1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.item h3 {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: turquoise;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.item a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.item a:hover ~ .item__overlay, .item a:focus ~ .item__overlay {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

img {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item__overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transition: transform 300ms;
  background-color: #82ebe0;
  transform: translate3d(0, calc(100% - 3.5rem), 0);
}

.item__body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.item__body p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#0" aria-labelledby="person1"></a>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590424744257-fdb03ed78ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
        <div class="item__overlay">
            <h3 id="person1" aria-hidden="true">Person 1</h3>
            <div class="item__body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#0" aria-labelledby="person2"></a>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590424744257-fdb03ed78ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
        <div class="item__overlay">
            <h3 id="person2" aria-hidden="true">Person 2</h3>
            <div class="item__body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#0" aria-labelledby="person3"></a>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590424744257-fdb03ed78ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
        <div class="item__overlay">
            <h3 id="person3" aria-hidden="true">Person 3</h3>
            <div class="item__body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#0" aria-labelledby="person4"></a>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590424744257-fdb03ed78ae0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
        <div class="item__overlay">
            <h3 id="person4" aria-hidden="true">Person 4</h3>
            <div class="item__body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the boxes to stay the original size before hovering.

Comment: @idiosyncratic are you sure? you will have a glitchy behavior when all the element will suddenly have their height increasing

Comment: But they will only increase in height when you hover over the individual box.

Comment: @idiosyncratic and all your layout will get glitchy because you are using grid and all the row will increase in height and will move all the content down of it

Comment: @idiosyncratic here is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/sqfo0uda/ and it look bad IMO